# Is AES-256 encryption & descryption a intense load for NodeJs server?

Tags: node.js, encryption, load-testing

Recently I'm about to set up a mciro service which only encrypt and decrypt token as a middleware with nodejs.
I expect this server is going to have around 300 rpm.
I'm new to this, before doing a load test, just want to hear from some experience or advice that what kind of machine setup is better for this.(My server is on AWS.)

Comment: if fork the job of encrypt/decrypt to a different thread/process and decouple the user needing to wait for things in the UI with websockets etc then doing 300 things a minute is wont be an issue, things go wrong when you need to wait for things to complete before responding, hanging up other users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [native nodejs crypto library](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) performs well: it's implemented in native (C++) code and can take advantage of hardware acceleration in common CPUs.

(npm packages using Javascript won't be as fast.)

5 requests per second should be OK on most AWS machines. If you use a reverse proxy server (like nginx) to handle https, it will be even better.

It's still a bit CPU intensive. You may want to use some [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) to keep the encryption code from stalling nodejs's main loop, especially if your server workload includes a lot of operations that don't use crypto. Or, if your machine is dedicated to this operation you might consider [clustering](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) your nodejs app.